# x86 assembly, printing 4 strings. Weird output

Tags: assembly, x86

So, I'm writing a program in C that converts typescript-like syntax to x86 assembly.
The following code:

```
hello = (x: string, y: string, z: string, a: string) => {
  print(x);
  print(y);
  print(z);
  print(a);
  return 1;
};

main = (argc: int, argv: Array<string>):int => {
  hello("first\n", "second\n", "third\n", "fourth\n");
  return 0;
};
```

gets converted to this x86 assembly:
( I have added some comments though, to explain what's going on )

```
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
  movl %esp, %ebp
  call main
  movl %eax, %ebx
  movl $1, %eax
  int $0x80

# a function that takes 4 arguments and prints them usin `print`
.type hello, @function
.globl hello
  hello:
  pushl %ebp
  movl %esp, %ebp
  pushl 20(%esp)
  call print
  addl $4, %esp
  pushl 16(%esp)
  call print
  addl $4, %esp
  pushl 12(%esp)
  call print
  addl $4, %esp
  pushl 8(%esp)
  call print
  addl $4, %esp
  pushl $1

  jmp return_statement

.type main, @function
.globl main
  main:
  pushl %ebp
  movl %esp, %ebp
  subl $8, %esp
  subl $12, %esp
  movl $0x0, 8(%esp)
  movl $0x0a74, 4(%esp)
  movl $0x073726966, 0(%esp)
  movl %esp, -4(%ebp)
  # end of "first"

  subl $8, %esp
  subl $12, %esp
  movl $0x0, 8(%esp)
  movl $0x0a646e, 4(%esp)
  movl $0x06f636573, 0(%esp)
  movl %esp, -8(%ebp)
  # end of "second"

  subl $8, %esp
  subl $12, %esp
  movl $0x0, 8(%esp)
  movl $0x0a64, 4(%esp)
  movl $0x072696874, 0(%esp)
  movl %esp, -12(%ebp)
  # end of "third"

  subl $8, %esp
  subl $12, %esp
  movl $0x0, 8(%esp)
  movl $0x0a6874, 4(%esp)
  movl $0x072756f66, 0(%esp)
  movl %esp, -16(%ebp)
  # end of "fourth"

  pushl -4(%ebp) # push string "first"
  pushl -8(%ebp) # push string "second"
  pushl -12(%ebp) # push string "third"
  pushl -16(%ebp) # push string "fourth"
  call hello
  addl $16, %esp
  pushl $0

  jmp return_statement

# print function takes one argument to print
# then calls `strlen` on that argument to later be used to write to
# stdout.
.type print, @function
print:
 pushl %ebp
 movl %esp, %ebp
 pushl 8(%esp)
 call strlen
 addl $4, %esp
 movl 8(%esp), %ecx
 movl %eax, %edx
 movl $4, %eax
 movl $1, %ebx
 movl %ebp, %esp
 popl %ebp
 int $0x80
 ret

# just a label to jump to when returning out of functions
# instead of re-typing this all the time.
return_statement:
 popl %eax
 movl %ebp, %esp
 popl %ebp

 ret

 .type strlen, @function
 strlen:
   pushl %ebp
   movl %esp, %ebp
   movl $0, %edi
   movl 8(%esp), %eax
   jmp strlenloop

 strlenloop:
   movb (%eax, %edi, 1), %cl
   cmpb $0, %cl
   je strlenend
   addl $1, %edi
   jmp strlenloop

 strlenend:
   movl %edi, %eax
   movl %ebp, %esp
   popl %ebp
   ret
```

Then I assemble this into a binary using

```
as --32 a.s -o main.o -g -W
ld main.o -o main -m elf_i386
```

And when I execute my program:

```
./main
```

I get this strange output:

```
firsȁÔÿ܁ÔÿðÔÿÔÿ Ôsecond
third
fourth
```

If I only print 3 strings, everything looks fine.

What am I doing wrong here?
I've spent several hours trying to figure this out.
I have almost scratched my whole beard off at this point.

Would really appreciate some help here.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, won't `movl %esp, -16(%ebp)` overwrite parts of the first string? Step through your `main` function in a debugger and watch the register values and stack contents.

Comment: I can't see a C program...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It's not relevant here, since it's in the assembly where the errors are

Comment: Then neither is the C tag.

Comment: @Michael I managed to solve it by adding (number of strings * 4) to `%esp` before I movl all the strings. I'm not sure why it works though

Comment: You know your `_start` doesn't actually pass argc, argv to main, right?  This program doesn't need it, but I assume that's on your TODO list, unless you plan to have `main` be special and access the process-startup stack state via the incoming `ebp` which points to argc, with argv above that?

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes it's on my TODO list, I actually had it implemented before but I removed it until I have some other stuff working

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

Before pushing all my strings to the stack,
I need to resize the stack to (number of strings * 4) to be able to fit
all of the string addresses.

So in this case, the solution is to do

```
subl $24, %esp
```

Before pushing all strings.

`6 * 4`
Where `6` is the number of strings in this case.

Now when I write the addresses to the stack, they wont overwrite previous strings.

Comment: That might happen to work, but is definitely not correct.  That puts ESP *above* your return address, making it vulnerable to being destroyed by a signal handler, debugger, or whatever.  The stack grows downward, you allocate new space with `sub` (or adding a negative number).  Make sure you `sub` enough space to point ESP *below* where you're going to store the strings.

Comment: @PeterCordes It was a typo, I meant to use `subl`